# FFI in Haskell, question about the LANGUAGE CPP and how to use a c struct with the FFI

Tags: haskell, ffi

I have some questions about the FFI in Haskell

1. I know i must use the language pragma `{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}` but what is the difference when i use `{-# LANGUAGE CPP, ForeignFunctionInterface #-}` what can i do "more" with the CPP
2. i use a function in c which use a `struct`, how can i handle this in the FFI?
3. when i have to use `CInt` and when just `Int`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. If you enable the `CPP` language extension, you can then legally encorporate C pre-processor syntax into your Haskell program.
2. To access a struct is a little more complicated. The easiest way is probably to use [the `Storable` typeclass](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/libraries/base-4.3.1.0/Foreign-Storable.html) to define `peek` and `poke` methods for each field of the struct. The [hsc2hs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/hsc2hs.html) tool can help.
3. You use `CInt` whenever you need to pass a Haskell `Int` to or from C, as this will ensure any required marshalling takes place (same goes for `CDouble`, `CString` and so on).

The X11 package has [many examples](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/X11/1.5.0.0/doc/html/src/Graphics-X11-Xinerama.html#XineramaScreenInfo) of defining and marshalling structs via the FFI.

---

More info in:

- [RWH ch 17.](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/interfacing-with-c-the-ffi.html)
- [FFI Introduction on the Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FFI_Introduction)
- [Foreign.* in the base library](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/libraries/base-4.3.1.0/Foreign-Storable.html)

Comment: i have a c function like: int foo(); must i write in the haskell signature Int or CInt, sofar i jzst used Int end all work

Comment: @ewggwegw: For the function it self, please use CInt. Using Int may or may not work, depending on your platform.

Comment: `foreign import ccall "foo" c_foo :: IO CInt`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

1. `CPP` is the C preprocessor. It allows you to use conditional compilation and makros. Usually, you don't need this, but it becomes useful, as soon as you have platform-dependent code, where the code to compile is decided by an external script (like with the autotools).
2. Have a look at [c2hs](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/haskell/c2hs/)
3. Use `Cint` only for the direct import. When writing a high-level binding, switch to `Int` as it doesn't requires the user to import the required libraries and is Haskell standard